# Lenel OnGuard 7.4 (on SQL Server 2014): how to add an employee with his card and disable?

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to create a process that registers employees with their card at the Lenel controls. In the same way, I need to disable the employees that will no longer be there.

I have the tables (`EMP`, `BADGE`), but is there something else to do after update those tables?

I am new in all this of Lenel, a little bit explanation will be welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, sir. Is your question about MS SQL Server or about some specific software uses MS SQL Server ?

Comment: Hi, thanks... this is about a software that uses MS SQL server.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with Microsoft SQL Server, that just happens to be where the data is stored. Seems like you need to contact Source Security's support team and hope that they can provide you with that information - or an appropriate procedure to do it through the application's GUI.